# Integrating heatmap values within specific window

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, integration

I am plotting a 2D function, using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build x,y mesh
nx = 1000; ny = 1000 
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, nx)
y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, ny)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Evaluate the Gaussian on grid
func = np.exp(-np.pi*((X)**2 + (Y)**2))
plt.imshow(func); plt.colorbar()
```

At this point, I'm integrating the function over the full range of the `x` and `y` vectors of the meshgrid, including the correct `dx` and `dy` increments. The value is shown in the title:

```
# Integrate the function
intval = np.trapz(np.trapz(func, y, dx=x[1]-x[0]), x, dx=x[1]-x[0])
plt.title('Integrated value = %s' % intval)
```

How can I integrate the same function over a *portion* of the window? say, between x[400:600] and y[400:600]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just passing that portion of the array?

```
cut = slice(400, 600)
intval = np.trapz(np.trapz(func[cut, cut], y[cut], dx=x[1]-x[0]),
                  x[cut], dx=x[1]-x[0])
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but I get an error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,199) (1000,999)`

Comment: @Dingo_chaser, woops, sorry about that.  What about the change I just made?

Comment: okay, I was missing the `slice` command in my earlier attempts. Thanks for your help! your solution works great.